# Does there exist a continuous function $f\colon \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $f(f(x))=-x$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, functional-equations

Does there **exist** a continuous function

> $f\colon \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $f(f(x))=-x$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: actually trying to disprove

Answer (score 7):

Hint: If $f(f(x))=-x$ then $f$ is a bijection and because $f$ is continuous it must also be either order preserving or order reversing.

Comment: not getting.........elaborate please

Comment: I think the hint should be enough for you to get to the answer. Write down the definition of an order preserving/reversing function and see what conclusions you can make from the above.

Comment: but why is $f$ a bijection?

Comment: $f\circ f$ is a bijection, and if $f$ was not a bijection then either $f\circ f$ would not be injective, or it would not be surjective - hence $f$ is bijective.

Comment: $f\circ f\circ f\circ f$ is the identity, hence a bijection. Thus $f$ has to be a bijection, too.